# jQuery Menu Hover Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I came across [this](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/stylish-navigation-menu-jquery/) tutorial for implementing a jQuery based menu. It's working perfectly, but I am wondering if it's possible to have a different coloured button for each link? Each link will have a different coloured button. Any idea how I can achieve this? You can view my work so far here. I tried making three different scripts for each button and having three different classes in CSS but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this, it's easier. Do it in your css instead of jQuery if it's giving you trouble.

```
#id_name:hover
{ 
    background:url(hover-image.png);
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. Will I get the same jQuery effect though? And in HTML, would it be `<li id="id_name"></li>`? See my source [here](http://xeenat.com/lima/)

Comment: if you are trying to get certain effects like slideDown, sildeUp, fadeIn, etc., I would use jQuery. If you paste your code here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the html on one side and the jquery on the other, I can sort it out for you

Answer (score 0):

what you needed to change was in the css for this selectors,

```
.hoverMenu, .hoverMenu:visited, .selectedMenu, .selectedMenu:visited
```

for hovered and

```
.normalMenu, .normalMenu:visited
```

for normal menu

with another image of your preferred colors.

Comment: So you're saying that I need to have two more of those for each class? As in `.hoverMenu2, .hoverMenu2:visited, .selectedMenu2, .selectedMenu2:visited`, and `.normalMenu2, .normalMenu2:visited`?

Comment: no, the classes are already in the css, you just have to look for it and change the background property

Comment: Hmm. I have. Currently, as you'll see [here](http://xeenat.com/lima/). But I want a different colour for the second link, and another different colour for the third link. Right now, with the type of settings there are, I can only have one colour, which is blue.

Comment: if that is the case, then you would have to create 3 different css for the different colored images that are going to be used. then you would have to change the js to call the different colored images

Comment: Ok. I tried that already but for some reason it wasn't working. This is what I added in the JS file. Could you please check if it's right? See Line 4 and Line 10: http://d.pr/Fnyr